# Using continuity sketch to "paste" a sketch anywhere

Tags: ipad, continuity

I would like to be able to insert sketches into the markdown notes editor Obsidian. This tool does not have any inbuilt support for continuity sketch.

However, it does allow me to paste images from the clipboard into the document. A kind of workaround that I have found is that I can take a screenshot of the size of the sketch that I want to insert and then open it in preview, where I can then use continuity sketch on that screenshot. I can then paste that image into obsidian.

But I feel like there should be a much smoother way to do this. It would be great if I could just press a keyboard shortcut and then use my iPad to sketch a quick drawing and when I'm done it just pastes this drawing wherever my cursor is.

Is there some way to achieve this, either natively or using some software?